# Oracle SQL Select Date Time with Earliest Time

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, group-by, min

I have a query that returns this

[image]

And I would like to to return this, where earliest hour of the same day is chosen

[image]

This is my query so far --- `MIN(I.CREATIONDATE)` does return the date-time format I want, I was hoping that `MIN` would select the earliest time.

```
   SELECT TO_CHAR(MIN(I.INCIDENTID))               AS "Incident ID",
          MIN(I.CREATIONDATE)                      AS "Creation Date",
          TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY')     AS "Date",
          TRIM(MO.DOMAINUSERNAME)                  AS "Login ID",  
          TRIM(M.MESSAGESUBJECT)                   AS "Email Subject"
   FROM   MESSAGE M 
   JOIN   INCIDENT I 
   ON     M.MESSAGESOURCE = I.MESSAGESOURCE 
   AND    M.MESSAGEID = I.MESSAGEID
   AND    M.MESSAGEDATE = I.MESSAGEDATE 
   JOIN   MESSAGEORIGINATOR MO
   ON     M.MESSAGEORIGINATORID = MO.MESSAGEORIGINATORID                   
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),
            TRIM(MO.DOMAINUSERNAME),
            TRIM(M.MESSAGESUBJECT)
```

Comment: On `1/26/2019 1:33:22 PM` the output `ID` should be `123` right, not `234`?

Comment: @Arulkumar Made correction :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`

```
with CTE as
(
select t1.*, 
       row_number() over (partition by trunc(creation_date) order by creation_date) rn
from Mytable t1
)
select *
from CTE
where rn = 1
```

Comment: for all purposes, this is a great approach. However my code is not working. Will tinker with it before deciding to post another question. Thanks!